# Need to click Javascript URL automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using below Javascript function for the Link in the homepage. Requirement is to link clicked automatically on page load.

Link-

```
document.writeln("<a href=\"javascript: live_chat_link(m_sTicketType,1);\" class=emp onmouseover='window.status = \"Live Chat\"; return true;' onmouseout=\"window.status = window.defaultStatus; return true;\">Live Chat</a>");
```

---

I have tried below steps like adding `document.getElementById('zautoclick').click();` and added `id="zautoclick"` before `href` but the problem is that my page does not show the link neither it loads the second page which comes after clicking on Live Chat.

Please share some logic to work auto click in my scenario.

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {})

Comment: @Piterden, Thanks for sharing. But I am unable to get my requirement. document.writeln("<a href=\"javascript..: live_chat_link(m_sTicketType,1);\" >Live Chat<../..a>");

Comment: `document.getElementById('zautoclick').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))`

Comment: okay i want to ask that are you loading Live chat box `onLoad` if it then and then it will click

Answer (score 0):

try this out
1)

```
$(function() {
    $('#watchButton').click();
});
```

2)

```
window.ready=function(){
  document.getElementById("linkid").click();
};
```

3)

```
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("linkid").click();
};
```